# Is my verification of an argument OK? And, a question about a Computer System to verify arguments

Tags: logic, theorem-provers

I found the following exercise in the Discrete Mathematics and Functional Programming book by Thomas VanDrunen.

**3.14.4**
(a) $\forall x \in A, P(x) \land \lnot Q(x)$
(b) $\forall x \in A, x \in B$
(c) $\forall x \in B, \lnot Q(x) \implies R(x)$
(d) $\therefore \forall x \in A, R(x)$

These are the steps I've used to verify the argument.

Suppose $a \in A$

(i) $P(a) \land \lnot Q(a) $
By supposition, (a), and Universal Instantiation.

(ii) $\lnot Q(a)$
Using (i) and Specialization.

(iii) $a \in B$
Using our initial supposition, (b), and Universal Instantiation.

(iv) $R(a)$
By (c), (iii), (ii), and Universal Modus Tollens.

(v) $\therefore \forall x \in A, R(x)$
By supposition, (iv), and Universal Generalization.

My questions are:

1. Is my verification OK? Or am I missing one step?
2. Since I will continue tackling the rest of the exercises, I am wondering if is there a Computer System aiding with the task of verifying these arguments? Sort of a Calculator, like when you perform an Arithmetic Addition and you want to verify if you did it well. I haven't played with [Coq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coq), and these last days I've been reading about [Agda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_(programming_language)), but I am not sure if those can be used for the task I am describing here.

Thanks!

--
Caleb

Comment: See [proof assistants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_assistant).

Comment: Correct; IMO step (ii) uses [Simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) and not Specialization.

Comment: For step (iv) the rules are: Universal Instantiation and Modus Ponens.

Comment: Mauro! You are right in (iv), indeed it is Universal Modus Ponens, I have a corrected version on my notebook, but I forgot to update it over here. And in (ii) I'll stick with Specialization: p ^ q, \therefore q. That's how is presented in the book, although I will check the link you are providing about Simplification. What else? Yeah, thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Karl!
Thanks for the link about proof assistants, I shall take a look at it next Saturday. Thanks again.